# Wordpress displaying content from sub pages

Tags: php

Im trying to pull in content from the 'sub pages' onto the homepage, I used the below to pull in content from the 'child pages' but unsure how to do this for the 'sub pages'

Does anyone know how this could be done?

-Parent page (4)

--Child page

-----sub page

--Child page

-----sub page

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $children = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => 4, 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
    if ( $children ) {
        foreach( $children as $child ) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?>
            </li>
    <?php } } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be looking for [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages):

```
$args = array(
  'child_of' => $post->ID
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

With the appropriate arguments I am almost certain that you can do what you need with that function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function [get_post_ancestors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)

Like in your question  for sub page `get_post_ancestors` return array with 2 value because it has two parents.

for eaxample

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $children = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => 4, 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
    if ( $children ) {
        foreach( $children as $child ) { 

            if( 2 <= count(get_post_ancestors($child->ID) ) ) :
        ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?>
            </li>
        <?php

            endif;

        } 

    }

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, hmm the above deosnt seem to work, if i change it to  '( 1 <=' it does pull in the child page titles though